# Does a failure to respond to FAA questions on ME disqualify for sport pilot?

Tags: faa-regulations, medical, pilot-certification

I had submitted a medical evaluation to pursue a private pilot certification. The FAA had requested further evaluation by specialists. I didn't respond to their questions. Does this disqualify me for a sport pilot license?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes I believe so.

While the Sport Pilot License only requires that you are medically qualified to get a driver's license there is a stipulation that if you had been denied an FAA medical previously then you cannot just use your driver's license as your medical.  If you don't respond to their questions then you will most certainly be denied the medical.

At this point I think it is best to answer their questions and finish out the process.  If your medical condition is under control and manageable the FAA will usually eventually grant you the medical however, a lot of paperwork, time and money may be required.

This is why you want to do your homework before the medical and be sure that you can pass it.  If you don't pass the medical then you cannot just simply fall back to the Sport Pilot License.

Comment: "there is a stipulation that if you had been denied an FAA medical previously then you cannot just use your driver's license as your medical" - I'm not sure that's correct. Under 14 CFR 61.23(c)(2)(ii), if you're a sport pilot using your driver's license to satisfy the medical requirements, then that privilege goes away when you **apply** for a medical, not when you're denied a medical. That privilege is then restored if you are issued a medical (and that privilege does not expire when the medical expires). I could be wrong, but that's my reading of the law.

Comment: @TannerSwett:  That makes sense.  When I said denied I meant that they applied but did not get the medical.  I think the OP thinks that if he doesn't respond to the FAA's questions he would not get denied and could still get the Sport's license but that is indeed not correct.